# Passing an extra element to $edit array when creating an account

Tags: forms, 6, hooks

I added an extra user registration validation critera in my custom module by implementing hook_user

```
if ('validate' == $op && 'user_register' == $edit['form_id'] && 'account' == $category && !$edit['remote_create_user']) {

    // Is the mail address OK?
    if ($email_in_use) {
    // No, set error on mail form field
    form_set_error('mail', t('Your email address is already associated with a account.'));
    }
```

I added the `!$edit['remote_save']` because I don't want this extra validation if I am creating accounts programmatically. The code I am using to create accounts is

```
 $form_state['values'] = $account;
    $form_state['values']['pass'] = array(
      'pass1' => $account['pass'],
      'pass2' => $account['pass'],
    );
    $form_state['values']['op'] = t('Create new account');
    $form_state['values']['remote_create_user'] = TRUE;
    $ret = drupal_execute('user_register', $form_state);
```

As you can see, I tried to add an extra form element called 'remote_save' `$form_state['values']['remote_save'] = TRUE;`. However, in the hook code above $edit['remote_save'] is empty so I can't use it to stop the extra validation. How can I pass a value from $form_state to the $edit array? Or is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: So I tried to use hook_form_alter with the code below

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)  { 
  if ($form_id == 'user_register') {
    $form['remote_create_user'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => FALSE);
  }
}
```

However this code `$form_state['values']['remote_create_user'] = TRUE;` which is in a separate module, does not set the value of $edit['remote_create_user']. The value of $edit['remote_create_user'] is still false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually trying to prevent a user from registering with an email that is in use, Drupal already has that built in. It also has a check that prevents users with an IP in the blocked IP address list to create an account.

**Solution**

Your flaw in the above code is that `drupal_execute` calls `drupal_process_form` which will rebuild the `$form_state['values']`. A solution could be to add a hidden/value form element to the user_register form with `hook_form_alter`. Doing that should allow you to send your custom value through `drupal_execute`.

Comment: I'm trying to verify it against an external database.

Comment: @glumbo Updated answer

Comment: I tried it but still had a problem. Check the original question.